# How to rewrite URL like this http://localhost/gestor_3.0/index.php?p=cadastros&t=operadoras

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How to rewrite URL like this

```
http://localhost/gestor_3.0/index.php?p=cadastros&t=operadoras
```

to

```
http://localhost/gestor_3.0/cadastros/operadoras
```

using htaccess and mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ReWrite your seo frindly url /cadastros/operadoras to the parsing php file

```
RewriteRule ^gestor_3.0/(.*)/(.*)/?$ /index.php?p=$1&t=$2 [L]
```